# Matrix derivative relationship

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

I'm working with a scalar function $f$ that depends on a matrix $A$ that is symmetrical and definite positive, so it is invertible. I computed the matrix derivative $\frac\partial{\partial A}f$. I also computed the derivative with regard to the inverse of $A$, namely $\frac\partial{\partial A^{-1}}f$ and I noted that the two derivatives seem to be linked through the relation:
$$A\left(\frac\partial{\partial A}f\right)A+\frac\partial{\partial A^{-1}}f=0$$

This works obviously for $1\times1$ matrices (i.e.: for scalars) but I wonder if this is a relation that also holds for all function $f$ of a symmetrical and definite positive matrix $A$?

Just to provide more details, we define $\frac\partial{\partial A^{-1}}f(A)=\frac\partial{\partial B}f(B^{-1})$, with $B^{-1}=A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is correct. You can demonstrate it using differentials as follows:

Let $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}^{-1}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
df
&=& 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{A}}:d\mathbf{A} 
=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{A}}:
-\mathbf{B}^{-1} (d\mathbf{B}) \mathbf{B}^{-1} 
=
-\mathbf{A}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\mathbf{A}:
d\mathbf{B}
\end{eqnarray*}
where the colon operator $:$ denotes the Frobenius inner product.
We have used in the last equality the fact that $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric.

Thus by identification
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{B}}
=
-\mathbf{A}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\mathbf{A}
$$